# How do I format, enumerate, and execute each line from LDAP query result?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep, zimbra

Okay so I **JUST** started bash scripting two weeks ago, and I ran into an issue last week that I just cannot fix. I'll describe my problem as best I can and I've included my script. I welcome any criticisms on what I am doing wrong with this code; Actually, I implore you to please provide as much criticism on my technique as you can so that I can learn from it.

---

### Objectives

I installed a new **Zimbra Collaboration Suite** for my company, and am in the process of migrating user accounts. I am trying to create a bash script to do the following:

1. Pull all user accounts from active directory via LDAP.
2. Format the LDAP query results to be used in a `zmprov ca` command.
3. Enumerate the lines of the formatted results.
4. Iterate through each line and run it as a `zmprov` command.

---

### Assumptions for the purposes of this example

- Name of the bash file = zdap
- My Active Directory domain = MYLOCALDOMAIN
- My username for LDAP = admin
- My password for LDAP = P@ssw0rd
- My LDAP IP address = 1.2.3.4

---

### Script

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Use this script to pull user information from Company Active Directory

argerror="Usage: company-ldap domain username"

if [ "$1" == "local" ]; then
    domain=MYLOCALDOMAIN
    ou=MAIN
else
    echo "$argerror"
    exit
fi

if [ -z $2 ]; then 
    echo "$argerror"
    exit
else
    user=$2
fi

password=P@ssw0rd

ldapsearch -h 1.2.3.4 -p 389 -D "cn=$user,ou=$ou,dc=$domain,dc=COM" \
           -w "$password" -b "ou=$ou,dc=$domain,dc=COM" \
           "(&(name=*)(mail=*)(givenName=*)(sn=*))" \
           'name' 'mail' 'givenName' 'sn' -LLL -S 'name' |
grep -B 1 'name\|mail\|sn\|givenName' |
grep -v '^dn:' | tr '\n' ' ' |
sed -e 's/ -- /\n/g' |
awk '{s=""; for (i=1;i<NF;i++) s = s $i " ";print $NF " " s}' |
sed -e 's/sn: /sn '\''/g' |
sed -e 's/ givenName: /'\'' gn '\''/g' |
sed -e 's/ mail: / /g' |
sed -e 's/ name: /'\'' displayName '\''/g' |
awk '{print "ca " $0"'\''"}' |
sed -e 's/ '\''$/'\''/g' |
awk '{($2 = $2 " tempzimbrapw1234"); print $0}' |
while read line ; do zmprov $line ; done
```

I call the command with this:

```
./zdap local admin
```

**Requested edit...**
The `zmprov` command for a given user (Joe Smith) looks like this:

```
zmprov ca joe.smith@mylocaldomain.com tempzimbrapw1234 sn 'Smith' gn 'Joe' displayName 'Joe Smith'
```

---

### Results and my Problem

- The ldap query runs perfectly (e.g., if I run that command separately, it will return the proper ldap results...so the issue isn't LDAP credentials/connection/query related).
- If I echo the command, it also looks just fine (e.g., if I type the
  command out to match the echoed version and it will actually add the
  account like I want).

However, when I run the zdap bash script I wrote, I expect to get a create account confirmation from Zimbra, but instead get this message:

```
zimbra@CPU-00154:~$ ./zdap local admin
usage: createAccount(ca) {name@domain} {password} [attr1 value1 [attr2 value2..
For general help, type : zmprov --help
```

Unfortunately I have tried too many solutions to list them all here. I've spent a week reading manuals, forums, etc. and have tried tons of tweaks, adjustments, new commands, etc. but to no avail.

Once again, I would greatly appreciate any criticisms regarding my script or overall method for accomplishing this. Please try to include examples with your suggestions so that I can see what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you in advance.

### EDIT:

I thought I should include the format of the LDAP query result so you can see what my command is working with:

```
dn: CN=admin,OU=MAIN,DC=MYLOCALDOMAIN,DC=COM
name: admin
mail: admin@mylocaldomain.com
--    
dn: CN=Jane Doe,OU=MAIN,DC=MYLOCALDOMAIN,DC=COM    
name: Jane Doe
mail: jane.doe@mylocaldomain.com
--    
dn: CN=Joe Smith,OU=MAIN,DC=MYLOCALDOMAIN,DC=COM    
name: Joe Smith
mail: joe.smith@mylocaldomain.com
```

---

## UPDATE

I managed to work out the issue using the `printf` command (special thanks to **rici** for that suggestion). The output from printf was this...

```
<|zmprov|> <|ca|> <|joe.smith@mylocaldomain.com|> <|tempzimbrapw1234|> <|#|> <|sn|> <|'Smith'|> <|gn|> <|'Joe'|> <|displayName|> <|'Joe|> <|Smith'|>
```

As you can see, the value of the last argument (displayName) was being misinterpreted.

Comment: It would help if you also added (1) what you expect the `zmprov` command line to look like, and (2) what it actually looks like. To get (2), put `echo` before `zmprov` in that line. Or, even better, use `printf '<|%s|> ' zmprov $line && printf '\n'`

Comment: @rici Excellent comment, I'll add that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would still be helpful if you included (2) from my first comment, especially the `printf` version:

```
printf '<|%s|> ' $line && printf '\n'
```

That `printf` statement will put `<|` `|>` around each argument, which makes it possible to see the difference between:

```
<|zmprov|> <|ca|> ... <|displayName|> <|'Joe Smith'|>
```

and

```
<|zmprov|> <|ca|> ... <|displayName|> <|'Joe|> <|Smith'|>
```

But I venture to guess that what you really want is:

```
<|zmprov|> <|ca|> ... <|displayName|> <|Joe Smith|>
```

Shell script quoting takes a bit of time to get your head around. Tools like that printf statement will help. Experiment a bit with simple commands. Pay attention to how variables are expanded. (And note that quotes in the *values* of variables are just ordinary characters.) Also make sure you understand the difference between `zmprov $line` and `zmprov "$line"`.

Finally, read the bash FAQ on quoting: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Also, `sed` can execute more than one command in a single invocation, and `awk` can do most of the things `sed` can do. I suspect you could simplify that massive line into a simple `awk` program.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "...make sure you understand the difference between `zmprov $line` and `zmprov "$line"`?

Comment: @Lopsided: Try both of them. Use the magic `printf` command. In particular, try them with values of `$line` which have spaces in them, like `line="This value is five words"`

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this. I'll mark this correct because it will certainly help me troubleshoot this issue. Thanks again.